# Неверный размер строки при использовании кирилицы

Tags: c++, ubuntu, кодировка, qt5, локаль

Пример задания: `char str[]="Это просто проверка программы."` `strlen(str)` показывает 56 символов (их 30). `cin.getline` при вводе этой же строки глотает 12 символов. Так же не работают и другие функции. Но при вводе латиницей все в порядке. Qt5.7 в windows работает нормально. Может кто подскажет проблему?

Comment: Возможно, дело в кодировке, и кириллические символы весят не по единице.

Comment: Как Вы вводите строку? И причем тут Qt?

Comment: При вводе с клавиатуры - char str[35]; cin.getline(str,35); Вводим строку "Это просто проверка программы." На выводе cout<<str; получаем "Это просто проверк". Я понимаю, что дело в кодировке, но как ее изменить?

Answer (score 5):

По умолчанию, в Ubuntu все в кодировке UTF8. Русские символы в ней занимают по два байта, а не по одному. strlen возвращает длину строки в байтах, а не в символах, поэтому ответ 56 (26*2+4=56) - правильный.

Comment: То есть, строковые константы по-умолчанию имеют кодировку UTF8 при компиляци под Убунтой?

Comment: в линуксе правилом хорошего тона является использование utf-8 везде. Ваша строка имеет ту кодировку, в которой сохранили файл. Qt надеется и очень рекомендует использовать utf-8 в сорцах. Вместо `char str[]` лучше использовать `QString`. там будет все нормально.

Comment: @Cerbo, в любом линуксе файлы по умолчанию в utf-8, как и input encoding у gcc/clang, мы это вроде с Вами как-то обсуждали уже.

Comment: Есть особые любители, которые делают дефолтную кодировку кои8 (или даже cp1251) и потом постят подобные вопросы:)